# How to get universal, moderately bigger mouse cursors on Ubuntu / GNOME?

Tags: gnome, mouse, cursor, accessibility

I am visually impaired. The default mouse cursor on Ubuntu is too tiny for me. It can be hard to find.

I used the gnome-tweak-tool to choose Large Mouse Cursors. The results of this operation have two problems:

1. The large mouse cursors do not appear everywhere. They only show up in certain applications, like the browser, while the gnome menus still have the regular sized mouse cursors that are difficult to find. I want large cursors everywhere
2. The "Large Cursors" (where they do appear) are obnoxiously large, to the point of being overkill. The Windows Standard Extra Large cursor scheme in Windows 7 (for comparison) is reasonably sized, but the "Large Cursors" in Ubuntu are too big.

This shouldn't be such a hassle to change, should it? What can I do to fix this?

BTW, I had similar problems when I was using Unity. I just switched to GNOME yesterday.

Comment: Have you tried Unity Tweak Tool? I don't think there is a way to make it work in every single application, because some manually control it (not cool, I know).  The one called "whiteglass" from UTT is just moderately bigger, but not too big.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible alternatives.

[Changing the cursor size in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589881/changing-the-cursor-size-in-ubuntu-14)
Read from "Better solution" onwards in the Answer

https://askbot.fedoraproject.org/en/question/26896/large-mouse-cursors-gnome3/
Read the last two comments